# What's the purpose of using method_field('PUT') or <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT" /> In Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

If I want to make an update request then i have to use?

```
{{ method_field('PUT') }}
```

Or

```html
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
```

Answer (score 13):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#form-method-spoofing

> HTML forms do not support `PUT`, `PATCH` or `DELETE` actions. So, when defining `PUT`, `PATCH` or  `DELETE` routes that are called from an HTML form, you will need to add a hidden `_method` field to the form. The value sent with the `_method` field will be used as the HTTP request method:

If you're using only `POST` or `GET` routes, you won't need it.